# Strange problem with .Net inheritance and member visibility

Tags: .net, inheritance, oop

I have a problem in a VB.Net class library which I have simplified greatly down to the following...

```
Public MustInherit Class TargetBase

End Class

Public Class TargetOne
    Inherits TargetBase
End Class

Public Class TargetTwo
    Inherits TargetBase
End Class

Public Class TargetManager
    Public Sub UpdateTargets(ByVal Targets As List(Of TargetBase))
        For Each objTarget As TargetBase In Targets
            UpdateTarget(objTarget)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateTarget(ByVal Value As TargetOne)

    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateTarget(ByVal Value As TargetTwo)

    End Sub
End Class
```

This will not compile due to a syntax error on the `UpdateTarget(objTarget)` line - *Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'UpdateTarget' can be called without a narrowing conversion*

So I changed the For-Each loop to use Object instead of TargetBase...

```
For Each objTarget As Object In Targets
    UpdateTarget(objTarget)
Next
```

This now compiles but I get a run-time error - *Public member 'UpdateTarget' on type 'TargetManager' not found.*

So I took the obvious next step of making the 2 *UpdateTarget()* overloads Public (instead of Private).

```
Public Sub UpdateTarget(ByVal Value As TargetOne)

End Sub

Public Sub UpdateTarget(ByVal Value As TargetTwo)

End Sub
```

This now works!

I can just about understand why changing it to Object would work but why must these methods be made Public when I am only calling them from within the same class  - I would rather they weren't available outside this class.

Can anybody explain this?

Thanks in advance (and sorry for the length of this question!)

**Additional**
Thanks for everyones answers so far. Ive got the workaround (make UpdateTarget methods Public) that makes it work. Another workaround would be to do a TypeOf check on objTarget and then DirectCast before calling UpdateTarget, like...

```
For Each objTarget As Object In Targets
    If TypeOf objTarget Is TargetOne Then
        UpdateTarget(DirectCast(objTarget, TargetOne))
    ElseIf TypeOf objTarget Is TargetTwo Then
        UpdateTarget(DirectCast(objTarget, TargetTwo))
    End If
Next
```

This will also work - I posted the question because I really wanted to understand why changing visibility of UpdateTarget from Private to Public got rid of the run-time error, totally against my understanding!

Comment: Did you mean to structure your UpdateTarget methods like this? Don't you mean to have one UpdateTarget method in each of the TargetBase subclasses? Then you can call objTarget.UpdateTarget. You probably got this compile error before because .net didnt know which class it was being passed (narrowing conversion)

Comment: Just out of curiosity "this now works" meaning - it calls the relevant method for the type of TargetBase (ie, correctly); or it always calls one of the methods?

Comment: @Jugglingnutcase - Thanks for your answer. I've already considered this and unfortunately it isn't possible. The code sample I've shown is extremely simplified (just to illustrate the problem) - in my real project I don't have access to TargetBase so can't add an UpdateTarget method to it.

Comment: @Adam: It works in that the correct UpdateTarget method is called

Comment: Out of more curiosity - if you change from private to public but leave the original passing of TargetBase in, instead of casting to object - does it work?

Comment: @Adam: No, still get the 'Overload resolution failed' error

Comment: Can you flag `Option Strict On/Off` and observe the error?

Comment: @Adam: Re: Option Strict On/Off - it doesnt make any difference!

Comment: Think I cracked it buddy, review my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Looks to me like it can't decide what method to use because you are using the base type of both method parameters.  TargetOne/Two are both valid TargetBases so both methods look the same to the resolution engine - meaning it can't pick.</strike>

However, I've no idea why the other changes make it work... let me think, update pending.

In C# I don't get this issue because you cannot forward cast TargetBase to TargetOne or TargetTwo... it gives a different compiler error - argument for method is invalid because it cannot implicitly convert base to derived.  The first compiler error you mentioned is basically the VB.NET equivalent.

I spotted this link, but I'm not sure if its for VB or VB.NET - either way, interesting read:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb18a48w.aspx

This also might relate to `Option Strict`, and co-variance in VB.NET 2010.  This article has a little overloads section, might prove useful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336029.aspx

**Update:** note that I've no clue why its suddenly working, this sounds like one for Jon Skeet or Eric Lippert.

**Update 2:** one thing I can suggest is for each situation (private to public / use of object) compile the application and review the IL using Reflector.  Basically, look for any differences - it could be that the compiler is adding something for you under the hood - either that, or the runtime is able to determine the correct method based on the current type.

**Update 3: think I got it.**  This quote from the following link:

> "An object is early bound when it is
>   assigned to a variable declared to be
>   of a specific object type."

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/earlybind.htm

Says that when you specify TargetBase, it's early bound and compiler complains.  When you specify object, it's late bound and the runtime complains when its private re this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3xt2was(VS.80).aspx

Therefore specifying public works for you.  The runtime is obviously able to late bind to the correct overload - a nice feature of late binding that was hidden by VB.NET for you :-)

Comment: Thanks Adam. Your Overload Resolution link is very informative. I'm guessing my code is failing on point 1) Accessibility - but I cant understand why

Comment: @barrylloyd I believe it failed at one with the compiler - but how it succeeds is a mystery.  The compiler / runtime must be doing something for you - perhaps reviewing the IL will yield some results.

Comment: Thanks Adam. From your Update 3 I got to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1(v=VS.80).aspx which has a yellow note saying that... 'Late binding can only be used to access type members that are declared as Public. Accessing members declared as Friend or Protected Friend results in a run-time error'.

Answer (score 3):

Though VB is not my specialty, I think I can answer your questions correctly.

In the first version of your program you have `UpdateTarget(objTarget)` where objTarget is of type TargetBase.  VB reasons as follows:

- The receiver of the call is "Me". That has a well-known compile-time type, TargetManager.
- The argument of the call is "objTarget". That has a well-known compile-time type, TargetBase.
- Since the receiver and the arguments all have types, we should do overload resolution to determine which version of UpdateTarget to call.
- Overload resolution determines that both versions of UpdateTarget require a potentially unsafe conversion from TargetBase to a more specific type.
- Therefore overload resolution fails.

In the second version objTarget is of type Object. VB reasons as follows.

- The argument of the call is of type Object.
- Again, overload resolution gives us nothing good here.
- Since overload resolution failed and something is of the Object type, and Option Strict is not on, generate code that does the analysis again *at runtime* using the *runtime* type of the argument.
- Late-bound analysis requires that the method called be *public*. Why? Because suppose this code were *not* inside TargetManager. Would you want to be able to call the private method from outside TargetManager via late binding but not via early binding?  Probably not. That seems dangerous and wrong. Unfortunately, VB's late binding does not distinguish between late binding done *inside* TargetManager and late binding done *outside*. It simply [requires that the methods be public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcf61s1(VS.71).aspx) in order to be called late bound.

In the third version, we go to late binding and the late binding succeeds at runtime.

What I would do here is:

1. Turn option strict on.
2. do TWO
   loops. Yes, that's not as efficient
   because you do the loop twice, but,
   big deal. If this isn't the slowest
   thing in your program then who cares
   if it gets a few milliseconds
   slower.

I don't know exactly what the VB syntax is, but in C# I would write this like this:

```
public void UpdateTargets(IEnumerable<TargetBase> targets) 
{
    foreach(var targetOne in targets.OfType<TargetOne>())
        UpdateTarget(targetOne);
    foreach(var targetTwo in targets.OfType<TargetTwo>())
        UpdateTarget(targetTwo);
}
```

Nice and simple. Go through the collection twice, first taking out the TargetOnes, then taking out the TargetTwos.

(Note also that if I'm not using any feature of List, then I'd make the argument IEnumerable instead, so that the method becomes more general.)

Comment: +1 lol got it right first go - took me some time Googling to get to that conclusion and even then I couldn't put it quite so eloquently! VB.NET isn't my strong suite - I just know how to do the basics to get by.  The thing I learnt today is implicit late binding - which as I've again learnt was the root of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

As Adam said, the compiler doesn't know which method it should be calling. However, this looks like the `UpdateTarget` method should be an instance method that each Target type overrides. This way you can iterate over the list and simply call `UpdateTarget` on `objTarget`.

The other advantage of this is you are better encapsulating the code. `TargetManager` doesn't need to know what the update actually does, just that it has to be called. Furthermore, down the road when you write a `TargetThree`, you don't have to change `TargetManager` in order to be able to update the the new type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already considered this and unfortunately it isn't possible. The code sample I've shown is extremely simplified (just to illustrate the problem) - in my real project I don't have access to TargetBase so can't add an UpdateTarget method to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Since you indicated in a comment that the normal polymorphic approach to this problem isn't possible in your case, I'd at least strongly advise changing your `TargetManager` class to have a single `UpdateTarget` method accepting a `TargetBase` parameter. Then check for the appropriate type within that method. This prevents the potential problem of having...

```
If TypeOf x Is A Then
    DoSomething(DirectCast(x, A))
ElseIf TypeOf x Is B Then
    DoSomething(DirectCast(x, B))
End If
```

...all over the place.

In other words, put that ugly check in one place:

```
Public Class TargetManager
    Public Sub UpdateTarget(ByVal target As TargetBase)
        Dim t1 = TryCast(target, TargetOne)
        If t1 IsNot Nothing Then
            UpdateTargetOne(t1)
            Return
        End If

        Dim t2 = TryCast(target, TargetTwo)
        If t2 IsNot Nothing Then
            UpdateTargetTwo(t2)
            Return
        End If
    End Sub

    ' I would also recommend changing the targets parameter type here '
    ' to IEnumerable(Of TargetBase), as that is all you need to do '
    ' a For Each loop. '
    Public Sub UpdateTargets(ByVal targets As IEnumerable(Of TargetBase))
        For Each objTarget As TargetBase In Targets
            UpdateTarget(objTarget)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateTargetOne(ByVal target As TargetOne)
        ' Do something. '
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateTargetTwo(ByVal target As TargetTwo)
        ' Do something. '
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

You've got [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) backwards.

Right off the bat, this is the way I intuitively think you *really* want this to work:

```
Public MustInherit Class TargetBase
    Protected Friend MustOverride Sub Update()
End Class

Public Class TargetOne
    Inherits TargetBase

    Protected Friend Overrides Sub Update()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TargetTwo
    Inherits TargetBase

    Protected Friend Overrides Sub Update()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class TargetManager
    Public Sub UpdateTargets(ByVal Targets As List(Of TargetBase))
        For Each objTarget As TargetBase In Targets
            objTarget.Update()
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: the OP understands the usual way of doing it, I think the question is more about the strange situation in which it starts to automagically work.

Comment: Thanks Dan, all good advice about refactoring the code, and good alternative workarounds.